# Video Background not playing properly on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Video background is not playing properly on Safari. It shows up on the bottom right of the screen which is not quite good to look at. But this works great on Chrome.

Here is the [link](http://devjentri.com).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<video autoplay  poster="" id="bgvid" loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
<source src="http://devjentri.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/deW_vid_final_.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://devjentri.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/deW-vid-final-.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS Code:

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Safari and on what OS? Link won't even load in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the vendor prefix version of the transform to your CSS rule:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

The complete rule should look like this:

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```